# “Ab” vs “seit” for time periods

Tags: word-usage, preposition, time

I have a problem understanding the exact difference between *ab* and *seit* when talking about the beginning of a time period. Can someone explain it?

I was corrected recently when I said:

> Seit dem nächsten Montag (Starting from the next Monday)

and was told, that I should use *ab*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Generally, I – as a German – would say that things that will happen in future are composed with *ab*.

> Ab morgen gehe ich arbeiten.

Things that began in the past but span to the present are composed with *seit*.

> Seit gestern gehe ich arbeiten.

Comment: Just as in English we also use different words: "From tomorrow I will be working in London", "Since yesterday I have been working in London".

Comment: [Googling *ab gestern*](https://www.google.com/search?q="ab+gestern") suggests that quite a few speakers of German also use *ab* for things that have started in the past (where I would exclusively use *seit*).  The same phenomenon exists in Dutch (speakers using *vanaf* where I would always use *sinds*).

Comment: @reinierpost I think the usage of *ab* and *seit* very much depends on the spoken idiom.

Comment: @MrOnkelChiller but I don't think anyone uses *seit* for something that will start in the future.

Comment: @reinierpost. No, I also don't think so. Did I assert that someone would do that?

Comment: @MrOnkelChiller: not at all; I just wanted to clarify that your statement doesn't mean "anything goes".

Comment: @reinierpost Ah, okay. That's alright, thank you.